# How to insert byte array into SQL table? 

Tags: sql

I try insert byte array in sql table, data type in table is VarBinary(Max), but it finish with this error:

**System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.**

Any adice, I am beginner with Sql...

Here is my code:

```
   byte[] key;
   byte[] iv;

   void generateTDES()
   {
       TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes;
       tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
       tdes.KeySize = 128;
       key = tdes.Key;
       iv = tdes.IV;
   }


    public void WriteUser(string _GUID, string _Name, string _Pass)
    {
        generateTDES();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();
        sql = "Insert into MembersTable (GUID,Name,Pass,CryptKey)"
        + "VALUES('" + _GUID + "','" + _Name + "','" + _Pass + "','" +key + "');";
        SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You will maintain more control over the types, protect yourself from injection attacks, and enjoy slightly better performace by parameterizing your query as follows:

```
    sql = "Insert into MembersTable (GUID,Name,Pass,CryptKey)"
    + "VALUES(@guid, @name, @pass, @key);";

    SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

    SqlParameter _guidParam = new SqlParameter("@guid", DbType.UniqueIdentifier);
    _guidParam.Value = _GUID;

    cmdIns.Parameters.Add(_guidParam);

    // Repeat for other parameters, specifying the appropriate types

    cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: True! But is there a type that can handle varbinary?

Comment: There's also an overload on the constructor where you can specify a field length; for example, new SqlParameter("@name", DbType.NVarChar, 128);

Comment: The type you want for a varbinary is, appropriately enough, "DbType.VarBinary".  In order to support more than 8000 bytes you have to explicitly specify the type as I did above.

Answer (score -1):

Prepare a hex string from the binary value and use it in the query for concatenation. a hex string will look like 0x123456789ABCDEF

Your final code will be like,

> ```
> hexStr = "0x1234FFCD5";
> sql = "Insert into MembersTable
> (GUID,Name,Pass,CryptKey)"
>          + "VALUES('" + _GUID + "','" + _Name + "','" + _Pass + "','"
> + hexStr + "');";
> ```

Check the code for constructing hex from binary [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_24580809.html)

> ```
> For Each bytTemp As Byte In bytAllBytes
>   'For your exact requirements
>   strHex &= bytTemp.ToString("X2") & " "
>   'however, you can use "X4" or "Xn" where replacing "n" with a numeric value will pad that number of zeros in the begining
> Next
> ```

Sorry, I speak VB... :)

Comment: This may work, but you're much better off parametrizing the query instead.